# Increment SQL result[0] in Node JS for loop

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, for-loop

```
main.con.query('SELECT name_ru AS catname FROM category', (err, resultsp) => {
      for(var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        console.log(resultsp[i].catname);
        }
    });
```

I need to get all results one by one. If I do `resultsp[0]` it works, it is giving SQL query result in JSON format outside of for loop. But it is not working with incrementing i
Cannot read property 'catname' of undefined

Comment: Please define "not working". Have you verified how many results you have?

Comment: Please add `resultsp`'s content to the question. Might be a data structure problem.

Comment: It is giving error that catname is not defined

Comment: Check what do you have with this  console.log(resultsp[i])

Comment: @SuleymanSah It gives me all three results gives 4th result as undefined. But the result contains only three rows

Comment: you need to use resultsp.length instead of i <=3

Comment: @SuleymanSah I used it

Comment: ok what problem you have now?  what displays when used console.log(resultsp[i])?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this error i write [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_defined) and [ReferenceError: "x" is not defined](https://airbrake.io/blog/javascript-error-handling/referenceerror-x-is-not-defined), You may have used this variable instead of having it defined or quantified. It may not even have anything to do with this piece of code. change your code, The loop size may be greater than the length of the result array

```
main.con.query('SELECT name_ru as catname FROM category', (err, resultsp) => {
      for(var i = 0; i < resultsp.length; i++) {
        console.log(resultsp[i].catname);
        }
    });
```

Comment: may be `resultsp` is empty. you should sure your result have data or query is right!